# Why do I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null with this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I continue to get the error on my home page of **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null** with this code.

```
// Load Carousel on Scroll.
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $loadedContainer = $('.pane-idevels-browse-genres-custom-content-load .pane-content');
    offsetY = $loadedContainer.offset().top;
    cH = $loadedContainer.outerHeight();
    wH = $(window).height();
    bodyScroll = $('body').scrollTop();
    htmlScroll = $('html').scrollTop();
    scrollTop = (bodyScroll == 0) ? htmlScroll : bodyScroll;
    carouselOffset = offsetY + cH;
    windowOffset = wH + scrollTop;
    if (carouselOffset <= windowOffset) {
        loadCarouselGenres($loadedContainer)
    }
})
```

Comment: Most possibly your selector is incorrect because `$loadedContainer` doesn't fetch anything. console log `$loadedContainer.length` to see is is fetching the element at all.

Comment: Formatting your code will be something nice.

Comment: where is the relevant html?

Answer (score 0):

maybe jQuery cannot find the element in this section

```
$('.pane-idevels-browse-genres-custom-content-load .pane-content');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $loadedContainer = $('.pane-idevels-browse-genres-custom-content-load .pane-content');

    if($loadedContainer){

       offsetY = $loadedContainer.offset().top;
       cH = $loadedContainer.outerHeight();
       wH = $(window).height();
       bodyScroll = $('body').scrollTop();
       htmlScroll = $('html').scrollTop();
       scrollTop = (bodyScroll == 0) ? htmlScroll : bodyScroll;
       carouselOffset = offsetY + cH;
       windowOffset = wH + scrollTop;
       if (carouselOffset <= windowOffset) {
         loadCarouselGenres($loadedContainer)
       }
    }
});
```